# Tkinter window in front of specific window (or all windows)

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, window-managers

I'm writing a small GUI program with python in tkinter for windows.
My window has to be in front of a fullscreen game-window.

At the moment, I use this line:

```
self.root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
```

which works for normal windows (browser, explorer, ...), but if I start the game to fullscreen mode, my window is hidden behind the game.

Why does this happen? Calls the game maybe something similar to `-topmost True` that overrides my attribute?

Is there another solution to my problem? Maybe it is possible to tell windows, that my window should be in front of a specific window (the game window)?

Comment: Is "my window" an instance of `Toplevel` created by the same program that creates the full screen window, or is this full screen game some other program?

Comment: the game is a completely unrelated programm (and it's closed source)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in windows according to [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-May/004678.html), you should be using the following code to make your job done:

```
import win32ui, win32con, win32gui
hwnd = int(eval(<toplevel>.wm_frame())) # Get the window info from the
window manager
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,
win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
```

But for this I have my finger crossed as you know the behavior for windows program remains in mystery because its closed source..